# SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe of table. Object does not exist when loading data using SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, opensuse, oracle18c

I am running into an issue with SQL Loader when I try and load data into a table that does exist. However, for some reason, SQL Loader returns errors. The table is in a pluggable database if that means anything or not, I am not sure but wanted to include it in the post here in case it helps figure out where the hang-up is.

Here is the control file:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE '/home/joshua/Practice_Data/Fitness_DB_Data/aug_2019_hiking_stats.csv'
INSERT INTO TABLE WALKING_STATS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(day_walked,cal_burned,miles_walked,duration,mph,shoe_id)
```

I have tried the `INTO TABLE` clause in three different variations: with just the table name (shown in this example) with the schema name (e.g., C##bigdaddy.walking_stats), and with the pdb prefixed as well (e.g., walking_data.c##bigdaddy.walking_stats).

All to no avail.

Some SQL commands to prove that the table does exist (at least from best I can tell as I am new to Oracle DB):

This is the pdb:

```
SQL> sho con_name;

CON_NAME
------------------------------
WALKING_DATA
```

User schema is there:

```
SQL> select user from dual;

USER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C##BIGDADDY
```

The table is there, albeit it's empty:

```
SQL> desc walking_stats;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DAY_WALKED                     DATE
 CAL_BURNED                     NUMBER(4,2)
 MILES_WALKED                       NUMBER(3,2)
 DURATION                       TIMESTAMP(6)
 MPH                            NUMBER(2,1)
 SHOE_ID                        NUMBER

SQL> select count(*) from walking_stats;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     0
```

The `TAB` view shows it:

```
SQL> select * from tab;

TNAME             TABTYPE    CLUSTERID
------------------------- ------------- ----------
WALKING_STATS         TABLE
```

The `user_tables` shows it and that it is valid:

```
SQL> select table_name, status from user_tables where table_name = 'WALKING_STATS';

TABLE_NAME        STATUS
------------------------- --------
WALKING_STATS         VALID
```

The `all_objects` table shows it also:

```
SQL> select owner, object_name, object_type, status from all_objects where owner = 'C##BIGDADDY';

OWNER       OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE STATUS
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
C##BIGDADDY WALKING_STATS   TABLE       VALID

SQL> select owner, object_name, object_type, status from all_objects where object_name = 'WALKING_STATS';

OWNER       OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE STATUS
--------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
C##BIGDADDY WALKING_STATS   TABLE       VALID
```

Here are the first few lines of the csv data file:

```
day_walked,cal_burned,miles_walked,duration,mph,shoe_id
2019-08-01,358.1,3.53,01:05:51,3.2,6
2019-08-02,354.7,3.46,01:05:12,3.2,6
2019-08-04,354.2,3.55,01:05:07,3.3,6
2019-08-05,351.3,3.52,01:04:36,3.3,6
```

Finally running sqlldr command on the command-line with the file path location argument using both the `sys` and `C##BIGDADDY` users (which both have INSERT privileges on the table):

sys user does not work:

```
joshua@linux-t1zu:~> sqlldr control='/home/joshua/Practice_Data/Fitness_DB_Data/upload_stats.ctl'
Username:sys as sysdba
Password:

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Oct 6 07:43:05 2019
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe of table WALKING_STATS
ORA-04043: object WALKING_STATS does not exist
```

Nor does user C##BIGDADDY:

```
joshua@linux-t1zu:~> sqlldr control='/home/joshua/Practice_Data/Fitness_DB_Data/upload_stats.ctl'
Username:C##BIGDADDY
Password:

SQL*Loader: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Oct 6 07:44:52 2019
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe of table WALKING_STATS
ORA-04043: object WALKING_STATS does not exist
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Any thoughts or ideas are much appreciated.
Im using Oracle 18c XE installed on openSuse Leap 15.0 if that helps any.
Thank you in advance.

**Edits**:

Two things I discovered that may help (or not). First as shown below, the `SYS` user cannot connect directly to the pdb, but can run `alter session` and set the container to it after connecting to the root container. However, table `walking_stats` is not visible to the `SYS` user:

```
    joshua@linux-t1zu:~> sqlplus SYS/password_here@WALKING_DATA

    SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Oct 6 10:39:38 2019
    Version 18.4.0.0.0

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

    ERROR:
    ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


    Enter user-name: SYS AS SYSDBA
    Enter password: 

    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
    Version 18.4.0.0.0

    SQL> sho con_name;

    CON_NAME
    ------------------------------
    CDB$ROOT
    SQL> alter session set container = WALKING_DATA;

    Session altered.

    SQL> sho con_name;

    CON_NAME
    ------------------------------
    WALKING_DATA

SQL> select user from dual;

USER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS

SQL> DESC WALKING_STATS;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object WALKING_STATS does not exist


SQL> select * from tab where tname ='WALKING_STATS';

no rows selected
```

Almost the same thing with user `C##BIGDADDY`:

```
joshua@linux-t1zu:~> sqlplus C##BIGDADDY/password_here@WALKING_DATA

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Oct 6 10:48:36 2019
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name: C##BIGDADDY
Enter password: 
Last Successful login time: Sun Oct 06 2019 07:45:07 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> sho con_name;

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
SQL> alter session set container = WALKING_DATA;

Session altered.

SQL> sho con_name;

CON_NAME
------------------------------
WALKING_DATA
SQL> desc walking_stats;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DAY_WALKED                     DATE
 CAL_BURNED                     NUMBER(4,2)
 MILES_WALKED                       NUMBER(3,2)
 DURATION                       TIMESTAMP(6)
 MPH                            NUMBER(2,1)
 SHOE_ID                        NUMBER

SQL> select count(*) from walking_stats;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     0
```

However, user `C##BIGDADDY` can see and select from the table `walking_stats`.

Comment: Can you see the table if you connect using SQL\*Plus instead of SQL\*Loader?

Comment: @ William Robertson. Yes, I am able to see the table. The example select count(*) from walking_stats; was from the SQL Plus environment. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson. Correction. The sys user cannot see table walking_stats but user C##BIGDADDY can.